# CoreImage kernels source codes

Tags: filter, ios5, blur, core-image

I want to implement some blurs using custom Core Image Filters. On Mac the blur filters are implemented, but on iOS 5.0 not.

Is it possible to find out how are the filter kernels implemented? I was looking in the Apple documentation for kernels source code with no results.

Thank you.